# Delete "TextChunk" in a PDF document with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working with iTextSharp to search for strings in a PDF document.

I have found a series of `TextChunk` and I would like to delete them.
Is there a way?
Alternatively, is it possible remove all text contained in a specific region (every single `TextChunk` has location and size)?

I would not insert "empty" image on the text to hide it, because the PDF is colored.

Thanks.

Comment: In its current state the text extraction strategies are designed for text extraction only, not for content manipulation. The `TextChunks` in the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` are already a representation stripped of most information not necessary for the task. For your task you might want to let yourself be inspired by the OCGRemover and OCGParser classes from the iTextSharp xtra classes, cf. http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/trunk/src/extras/iTextSharp.xtra/iTextSharp/text/pdf/ocg

Comment: @hicurin I'm afraid that bounty is not a good invest on this topic. A fairly complete solution would require an overhaul (or an improved re-implementation) of the itext parser package. And a simplified solution is not too different from the aforementioned `OCGRemover` and `OCGParser` sample, i.e. an easy exercise for the reader.

Comment: You might want to read [Bruno's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24037497/1729265) on the topic of redaction.