# How to create and apply redactions?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there any way to implement PDF redaction using iText? Working with the Acrobat SDK API I found that redactions also just seem to be annotations with the subtype "Redact". So I was wondering if it's possible to create those in iTextSharp as well?

With the Acrobat SDK the code would like simply like this:

```
AcroPDAnnot annot = page.AddNewAnnot(-1, "Redact", rect) as AcroPDAnnot;
```

(I haven't be able to apply them though as `annot.Perform(avDoc)` does not seem to work. Ideas?)

In iTextSharp I can create simple text annotations like this

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(stamper.Writer, rect, "Title", "Content", false, null);
```

The only other option I found so was was to create black rectangles as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308383/how-to-redact-pdf-using-itextsharp), but that doesn't remove the text (it can still be selected). I want to create redaction annotations and eventually apply redaction.

**// Update:**

As I finally got around to create a working example I wanted to share it here. It does not apply the redactions in the end but it creates valid redactions which are properly shown within Acrobat and can then be applied manually.

```
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream);
            // Create a stamper
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
                {
                    // Add the annotations
                    int page = 1;
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(500, 50, 200, 300);

                    PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, rect);
                    annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));

                    annotation.Title = "My Author"; // Title = author
                    annotation.Put(new PdfName("Subj"), new PdfName("Redact")); // Redaction "Subject". When created in Acrobat, this is always set to "Redact"

                    float[] fillColor = { 0, 0, 0 }; // Black
                    annotation.Put(new PdfName("IC"), new PdfArray(fillColor)); // Interior color

                    float[] fillColorRed = { 1, 0, 0 }; // Red
                    annotation.Put(new PdfName("OC"), new PdfArray(fillColorRed)); // Outline color

                    stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
                }

        }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response, but we have implemented redaction in iText 5.5.4, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks for the update! Once you port this one to C# I'll kiss you ;)

Comment: And there you go! :) Just saw in the changelog of 5.5.5 that redactions have been ported to iTextSharp!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:** Creating redaction annotations

iText is a toolbox that gives you the power to create any object you want. You are using a *convenience method* to create a Text annotation. That's scratching the surface.

You can use iText to create any type of annotation you want, because the `PdfAnnotation` class extends the `PdfDictionary` class.

This is explained in chapter 7 of my book ["iText in Action - Second edition"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiHFZ.jpg). [GenericAnnotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpuJl.jpg) is the example that illustrates this functionality.

If we port this example to C#, we have:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(writer, rect);
annotation.Title = "Text annotation";
annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.TEXT);
annotation.Put(PdfName.OPEN, PdfBoolean.PDFFALSE);
annotation.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS,
  new PdfString(string.Format("Icon: {0}", text))
);
annotation.Put(PdfName.NAME, new PdfName(text));
writer.AddAnnotation(annotation);
```

This is a *manual* way to create a text annotation. You want a `Redact` annotations, so you'll need something like this:

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(writer, rect);
annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
writer.AddAnnotation(annotation);
```

You can use the `Put()` method to add all the other keys you need for the annotation.

**Answer 2:** How to "apply" a redaction annotation

The second question requires the itext-xtra.jar (an extra jar shipped with iText) and you need at least iText 5.5.4. The approach to add opaque rectangles doesn't apply redaction: the redacted content is merely covered, not removed. You can still select the text and copy/paste it. If you're not careful, you risk ending up with a so-called [PDF Blackout Folly](http://slashdot.org/story/06/06/22/138210/more-pdf-blackout-follies). See for instance the NSA / AT&T scandal.

Suppose that you have a file to which you added some redaction annotations: [page229_redacted.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/page229_redacted.pdf)

[image]

We can now use this code to remove the content marked by the redaction annotations:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(stamper);
    cleaner.cleanUp();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

This results in the following PDF: [page229_apply_redacted.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/page229_apply_redacted.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, the red rectangle borders are replaced by filled black rectangles. If you try to select the original text, you'll notice that is is no longer present.

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work so far. 
But is there also a way to apply the redaction?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply". When you do `writer.AddAnnotation(annotation)`, you add the annotation to the document. How is "to apply the redaction" different from adding it to the document?

Comment: He means to redact the area covered by the redaction annotation and flatten the annotation using the redaction annotation appearance.

Comment: exactly. Before applying a redaction it is just an annotation which can be removed again, i.e. the content underneath it is still visible

Comment: If you flatten an annotation, then it's no longer an annotation. That is not what was asked in the original question: find an equivalent for `AcroPDAnnot annot = page.AddNewAnnot()`. Now the question is completely different: you want to use `PdfStamper` to stamp whatever content on an existing PDF document.

Comment: Well yes and no. Before applying it, a redaction is a special annotation. But without applying it, there is no sense it marking a text to be redacted in the first place ;-)

Comment: It seems that you see PDF as a format for editing. That's not the case.

Comment: No, I dont want to edit my PDFs. I am just looking for a way to programatically use the Redaction feature which is available in Acrobat:
1) Mark parts of the document to be redacted 
2) Apply the redaction (produce a flattened version of the PDF)

Comment: OK, then `PdfStamper` is what you need, and you can skip 1).

Comment: I don't really think so. Using the first (Annotation) method, I am able to create redactions which are shown as such when I open the PDF afterwards in Acrobat. There I can say "apply redaction" and a flattened version is produced. So I am "only" looking for a way to perform this step.

Comment: You're confusing me. Are you saying that you have the PDF *with* redactions? If so, you can flatten them if the redactions have a DA (Default Appearance). If not, you need to create your own appearance for them using the code explained in Answer 2. So the real question is: do your redaction annotations have appearances?

Comment: By the way: your question is very misleading.

Comment: Not sure we are still talking about the same thing ;-)
Do you know the Acrobat Redaction feature? If you got Acrobat, open any PDF, go to Tools, Protection, Mark for redaction.

Comment: I will prove that we're talking about the same thing and explain why you're making wrong assumptions. Give me a moment to make some screen shots.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation! It's clearer now what you meant... But short answer is, that there is no way to apply the redaction using itext in the same way as acrobat, correct?

Comment: Correct. It would take several months of programming.

Comment: As applying the Redaction is a special action (in fact, the contents underneath the annotation is irrecoverably destroyed), it might be a good idea to let Acrobat do that. I am not sure whether Acrobat just removes the objects, or whether it creates a new document without those objects. The latter approach would be proper. Keep in mind that the idea of Redaction is to make sure that the redacted parts can not be revealed anymore. (and there are many high profile highly embarrassing bloopers out there where Redaction was done wrong)

Comment: Yes, Max, that's what I meant when I referred to the PDF Blackout follies. Note that we have done a project for a customer that was similar: in that case, we indeed rewrote the PDF and we removed the original content from the content stream, but also from possible artifacts that are saved with the PDF. For instance: if you save a PDF from AI, removing the data from the content stream isn't sufficient. You also have to remove the /PieceInfo that could possibly contain the original source (including the removed data).

Comment: Let's say I would want to use Acrobat, does anyone know if there is an API function to accomplish this (only applying redactions)?

Comment: @silent: you should get access to the according command using IAC/DDE (Windows) or Applescript/System Events (Mac); have a closer look at the according documentation within the Acrobat SDK.

Comment: @Bruno: wouldn't the /PieceInfo be properly discarded when you write a completely new document from scratch? (if I remember correctly, the industry standard tool for Redaction simply does that).

Comment: Talking about iText: it depends. If you use `PdfCopy` (or related classes), then `/PieceInfo` disappears. If you use `PdfStamper`, then `/PieceInfo` is preserved (removing it would be considered a bug). Note that iText is a toolbox. Redaction doesn't come "out-of-the-box". If you implement Redaction-like functionality using iText, you have to be well-aware of what you're doing. Each tool has its own specific purpose.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll leave it with that :) Just one last question: Do you know how I can change the color of the redaction overlay (using method 1)? By default it seems to be white...

Comment: I have applied a minor update to my answer right under the first screen shot. I shows you where to look for the color values in the annotation.